# How to set Archive Version in WLST offline deploy?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

Is it somehow possible to set Archive Version in the **WLST** offline deployment?

My current deployment is:

```
# Create Application
# ==================
cd('/')
app = create(appname, 'AppDeployment')
app.setSourcePath(appdir + '/' + apppkg)
app.setPlanPath(appdir + '/deploymentplan.xml')

# Assign application to AdminServer
# =================================
assign('AppDeployment', appname, 'Target', 'AdminServer')
```

If the WAR file doesn't contain a version in the MANIFEST, then it works correctly... But when the WAR file is versioned in the MANIFEST, it crashes with:

```
[Deployer:149268]Static deployment of non-versioned application "<app name>" failed due to a version being defined in its manifest file.
```

Thanks in advance.